# Docker create container mysql and can not connect this database

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

This is my Container Which Is I opened

```
  db:
    container_name: admin_db
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    networks:
      - app
```

When I Run This Code

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID mysql -uroot -p
```

It gives Such kind of Error, I entered this password 12345

```
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of `MYSQL_USER`, this is used to specify a secondary user, if you use this config should work:

```yaml
 db:
    container_name: admin_db
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: admin_db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
    networks:
      - app
```